# connecting to mysql database via asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

i'm trying to connect to MySQL db in asp.net (i guess that im noob ;p)

I'm really new in this thing (mean asp)

I'm using VS 2013 Pro, MySQL Server 8.0.11 and i've installed Connector/Net and mysql for visual studio 1.2.8

In Server Explorer tab i have the connection with db and i see my table, tests are successful (both .NET Framework Data Provider for MySQL and MySQL Database (MySQL Data Provider))
[image]

but i cannot get the connection via code (?)

when i'm trying with this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQL"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT imie FROM pracownicy", connection))
                using (OdbcDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                        Response.Write(dr["imie"].ToString() + "<br />");
                    dr.Close();
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("An error occured: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

and this is part of web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MySQL" connectionString="Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0.11 Driver};server=localhost;uid=marcin;pwd=pass;database=test" />
```

and im getting somethig like this:
An error occured: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC driver manager] The name Data source can not be set, and the default driver is not provided

I also try this:

Added reference to MySql.Data.dll

and the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=marcin;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=test;password=pass");
        }
    }
}
```

only with that im getting

```
Warning     The primary reference "MySql.Data, Version=8.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5".
```

and

```
Error   The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to increase your target to .NET 4.5.2 or later.  You are trying to use a MySQL dll that was built against 4.5.2 and you are only on 4.5.0.

Comment: i found this https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks
should i choose developer pack or runtime ?

Comment: Developer pack is the one you need